# How to get each element in a JSON array with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "CNPJ_PSSA_JUDC": "00000000",
  "NOME_PSSA_JUDC": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA",
  "DOCT_SCIO": [
    "11111111111",
    "00000000000"
  ],
  "NOME_SCIO": [
    "PESSOA DE CPF 11111111111",
    "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000"
  ],
  "DCRC_CRGO": [
    "Sócio",
    "Sócio-Administrador"
  ]
}
```

And I need this output with JOLT:

```json
[
  {
    "CNPJ_PSSA_JUDC": "00000000",
    "NOME_PSSA_JUDC": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA",
    "DOCT_SCIO": "11111111111",
    "NOME_SCIO": "PESSOA DE CPF 11111111111",
    "DCRC_CRGO": "Sócio"
  },
  {
    "CNPJ_PSSA_JUDC": "00000000",
    "NOME_PSSA_JUDC": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA",
    "DOCT_SCIO": "00000000000",
    "NOME_SCIO": "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000",
    "DCRC_CRGO": "Sócio-Administrador"
  }
]
```

My question is: how can I get each element of a JSON array with JOLT?

Every time I find myself facing the difficulty of traversing the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  { // nest non-arrays within a common object in order to use it 
    // within the next spec
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*PSSA_*": {
        "@": "&(1,2).&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*SCIO|DCRC_CRGO": {
        "*": {
          "@2,JUDC": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go 2 levels up the tree to grab the values of the "JUDC" array
          "@": "[&1].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one per each identical components of the arrays
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your solution worked VERY well.

The biggest point is that I need help understanding how to loop through the array or parts of JSON and use those parts in isolation.

I really appreciate your help but I still get lost trying to understand the #, @, &, () and [] functions in JOLT.

Could you help and explain me, please?

I apologize for bothering and insisting so much.

I leave you a tip: write a book about JOLT, you are the most knowledgeable person on this subject that I know.

Comment: Hi @MateusCostaLuz thank u for the compliments. # stands for fixed values if prefixes a literal and stays on the LHS, and if it'is on the RHS, then it stays square bracketed along with an integer such as [#2] and this particular value is nearly identical to [&1]. The difference is due to the initial value of their indexes. They all produces array-wise results. As an example &1 represents going the tree one level up whether it's on the RHS or LHS, while square bracketed one such as [&1] stays only on the RHS.. @ on the LHS represents the value from just one level up while $ is so for the key.